# UNIX sort with -c

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a file ( 3 columns tab delimited), I need to check if file is sorted or not
Example:

```
chr1    9999999 10000125        C57T3ANXX:7:2114:14205:58915/2  50      -
chr1    10010918        10011044        C57T3ANXX:7:2310:08814:31632/1  50      +
chr1    10011185        10011311        C57T3ANXX:7:2310:08814:31632/2  50      -
```

On above file, I use

```
cut -f1,2 f |sort -cn,
```

which give me

```
sort: -:2: disorder: chr1       10010918.
```

I am not sure why, as the file is already sorted. I get same order when I use

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort -cn` assumes that the entire line is the key, because the line starts with a non-numeric character it resorts to non-numeric mode for that key, which is the only one

enable numeric mode for you keys:
`sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -cn`

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?